# dual boot : ACPI errors

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bios, acpi

i'm very new to **Linux, ubuntu**, i have windows 10 on my HP EliteBook x360 1030 G2 i5 7th and Ubuntu alongside (dual boot), when i try to boot Linux, it can't boot and shows multiple ACPI errors. please someone help me ! here you can see the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/8BdPXXT sorry i can't copy the errors, you can see them in the screenshot.
i tried adding nouveau.modeset=0, modeset.. nothing change or solve the problem